# App starts in 1.5 emulator but doesn't in 1.6

Tags: java, android

My app works on 1.5 emulator and 1.5 device. When i try to start it on 1.6 emulator, it produces strange exceptions (doesn't even start). I don't have any 1.6 device to try this app if it works on a real device.
I get some warnings in Eclipse ( warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a broken compiler.) and get cant rid of them (i think they come from some apache jars that i need to make http multipart posts).
 Is it possible that this jars are cause for my exceptions in 1.6 or is it something else?

My logacat:

04-29 16:14:55.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.poslji.gor/com.poslji.gor.FormFiller}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'null' as integer
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'null' as integer
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:333)
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at com.poslji.gor.FormFiller.nastavi(FormFiller.java:322)
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at com.poslji.gor.FormFiller.onCreate(FormFiller.java:188)
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
04-29 16:14:55.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for a parse exception @ com.poslji.gor.FormFiller.onCreate(FormFiller.java:188), use try catch

Edit:

Then again I am not sure how it ran in 1.5 :D

Comment: I found the problem. I was reading preferences at that line, but at the first launch on this emulator, the value for that setting was null.
Thanks for teaching me how to find bugs.

Answer (score 0):

" Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'null' as integer"

A configuration file missing, so a lookup fails and returns null?

Comment: Which configuration file do you mean?

Comment: No idea.  Perhaps this line "com.poslji.gor.FormFiller.nastavi(FormFiller.java:322) " can tell you more.